# Threading for binding multiple gridview

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-4.0

I am binding 4 gridviews on button click. Like this

```
        gv1.DataSource = GetData("Mill");
        gv1.DataBind();

        gv2.DataSource = GetData("Factory");
        gv2.DataBind();

        gv3.DataSource = GetData("Garage");
        gv3.DataBind();

        gv4.DataSource = GetData("Master");
        gv4.DataBind();
```

They all are using the same method for getting the result and they are also taking time to load. Is there any way I can run them parallel? I afraid, because they are using same method to get the data.

Is it possible to do threading for them. How?

Please help

Comment: I have asked the same question in the edit part of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839001/threading-for-methods-on-button-click but I think that some part of it already answered and that question is end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) about asynchronous pages.

Comment: Thanks for you instant reply. But I am very new to threading and I have an urgent requirement to bring this code alive. Is there any simple way I can achieve the same ?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite, threading is never simple. If you ever dive into it I would recommend you reading about it carefully first or you will have lots of problems.

Comment: can you please look into this question and guide me the best way I can do for threading method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839001/threading-for-methods-on-button-click